# How to select the first beat in bar using Sibelius?

Tags: notation, sibelius

I know it is possible to select a position on bar or a note value in advanced filters. The note i want to select is the first beat in bar. How could you select it without interrupting the whole score?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine you're looking for something like this, yes?

[image]

This isn't entirely right, in that it is treating the pickup like a full bar, so I would clear those notes with Ctl-click. I also work with an older version of Sib (4), so your mileage *may* vary (although I don't imagine the filtering options have changed very much).

What I did here was to work with advanced filtering for "Notes and Chords", clear the "Any" checkbox under "Position in bar", choose a semibreve value, and check the "Plus multiples" checkbox.